# Sphinx: combining phrase and field-end operator

Tags: sphinx

When combining [phrase](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax) and [field-end](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax) operators, Sphinx (2.0.4-release) seems to ignore the field-end operator.

E.g. when searching for

```
"^some phrase$"
```

it will correctly find "some phrase", but it will also find "some phrase with more words", thus ignoring the field-end operator.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [bug in Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=909) until version 2.0.5-release.

As a workaround use space after the field-end operator, so

```
"^some phrase$"
```

will become

```
"^some phrase$ "
```